# Как записать и считать excel таблицу не перезагружая скрипт?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

```
import openpyxl;
from openpyxl import load_workbook;

write = load_workbook('./test.xlsx');
write_sheet = write.active;

read = openpyxl.open("./test.xlsx", data_only=True);
read_sheet = read.active;

def read_excel():
    print(read_sheet['D2'].value);

def write_excel(a,b,c):
    write_sheet['A2'] = a;
    write_sheet['B2'] = b;
    write_sheet['C2'] = c;
    write.save('./test.xlsx');
    write.close();
write_excel(1,2,3) #Обновляет данные
read_excel() #Выводит None, если не перезагрузить скрипт
```

Вот псевдокод. После вызова *write_excel(1,2,3)* он обновляет файл *test.xlss*, но если в этом же выполнении вызвать *read_excel*, то будет None. Можно ли без перезагрузки скрипта сделать так, чтобы *read_excel* смог считать данные, можно ли это как-то сделать без перезагрузки скрипта? (в D2 помещена формула)

Comment: Делайте `read = openpyxl.open("./test.xlsx", data_only=True);` не в начале скрипта, а перед read_excel

Comment: @insolor, не работает, пытался в самой функции открывать, там оно тоже так не работает.

Comment: Так он и после перезагрузки скрипта None показывает. Только если файл test.xlsx открыть в excel, пересохранить, тогда результат формулы обновится.

Comment: P.S. т.е. ни Python в целом, ни openpyxl не вычисляют результат формул, вычисляет excel. Значит придется как-то запускать excel (или другое приложение того же типа, например libre office calc) через python, и пересохранять файл.